# Is there an overview over recommender system architectures?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, databases, nosql

I want to learn more about the recommender system topic.
I am very interested in the usage of different database systems for this use case.

My problem is that I cannot find a good overview of different **architectures of recommender systems**, especially with the focus on the database part.

Can someone help me out with a good reference or some own thoughts?

**Thanks a lot**. As interesting as this topic is for me as hard it seems to get some concrete information about it.

Answer (score 4):

A great source is the personal page of [Xavier Amatriain](https://xamat.github.io/) (former Head of Engineering at Netflix and Quora). There are several links at publications detailing the system and architecture of recommender systems. In particular you could take a look at this [Building industrial-scale real-world recommender systems](https://xamat.github.io/pubs/recsys12-tutorial.pdf), there is also this talk [Lessons Learned from Building Real­-Life Recommender Systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJOtr47V0eo) and this blog post [System Architectures for Personalization and Recommendation](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/system-architectures-for-personalization-and-recommendation-e081aa94b5d8)